# Is it possible for socket.io to work on shared hosting?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, cpanel, web-hosting

Hi,

Im on a shared hosting and I had my host install node.js, then I installed socket.io myself on my user folder. I start the service from the terminal on cpanel or a shell session and my socket.io works. However, as soon as I close the terminal window the service goes down and the app wont work anymore. Why is this? Does it need to be started by the root user in order to stay on?

My app.js file looks like this by the way:

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = { path: "" };
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);

app.get('/newchat', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public_html/myapp/index.html', { root: '../' });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', msg => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`running`);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need to run the app as a service, try [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: it says I dont have the permissions so only root can run it.

Comment: ok then run `node app &`, but if it crashes it won't auto restart

Comment: sorry, it didnt work either. As soon as I close the terminal window the app just stops working.